# How does Chrome developer tools emulate touch events?

Tags: javascript, events, touch, emulation

I have tried a few different Javascript tools/hacks/frameworks that emulates touch events on a PC, but none does it as flawlessly as Chrome's developer tools. How is it done? Can it be done as good as that with Javascript?

Let me give you an example to illustrate what I mean: I have built a webapp, exclusively for touch screens, containing a bunch of draggable elements. Now I also want to make it available for ordinary web browsers. The simplest way to do this is to use a small Javascript framework that maps mouse events to touch events, like [touche.js](https://github.com/davidcalhoun/touche). The problem with this approach is that if I drag fast, the mouse pointer will move out from the draggable, which then immediately stops. When I use Chrome's built-in emulated touch events (in Developer Tools), this never happens. I can drag as fast as I want. The code is exactly the same, except for the framework.

Do you have any ideas why this is happening, and if there is any remedy to the problem?

Comment: Show your code. What issues were you having?

Comment: I think he asked a theoretical question of how it could be done. He didn't provide us code as he don't want us to answer with an implementation.

Comment: Yes, sharethis is right. This is a general, theoretical question.

Answer (score 0):

Probably on a lower level than javascript. Try a [search for touchstart in the chromium code base](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#search/&q=touchstart&sq=package%3achromium&type=cs) and you can see that it's mostly C++ code :(